# Optimizing query with huge amount of data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I optimize the query. I looked at the execution plan and created all the index. Every table has huge data. And this query execution time is very large. By looking at the query could you please suggest where can I optimize more.

If I give little background of the query the structure like:

1. There are many companies
2. Each company can have multiple managers
3. Data is in pagination format
4. Filter on #parent_manager so another temp table created parent_manager_filter just to use for the filtering purpose as #parent_manager has name in "," separated format

```
CREATE TABLE #parent_manager 
(
    cid NUMERIC(18) PRIMARY KEY, 
    name NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    code NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

CREATE INDEX cte_parent_manager ON #parent_manager(cid);

CREATE TABLE #parent_manager_filter 
(
    cid NUMERIC(18), 
    name NVARCHAR(1000), 
    code NVARCHAR(1000)
);

CREATE INDEX cte_parent_manager_filter_idx ON #parent_manager_filter(cid);

INSERT INTO #parent_manager 
    SELECT DISTINCT
        mgrc.cid,
        name = CAST (STUFF ((SELECT ', ' + CAST(c.company_name AS varchar(2000)) 
                             FROM manager_company mc 
                             INNER JOIN company c ON (mc.mgr_cid = c.cid ) 
                             WHERE mc.cid = mgrc.cid 
                               AND c.company_name IS NOT NULL
                             FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS VARCHAR(2000)),
        code = CAST (STUFF ((SELECT ', ' + CAST(c.code AS varchar(2000)) 
                             FROM manager_company mc 
                             INNER JOIN company c ON (mc.mgr_cid = c.cid ) 
                             WHERE mc.cid = mgrc.cid 
                               AND c.company_name IS NOT NULL
                             FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS VARCHAR(2000)) 
    FROM
        manager_company mgrc 
    INNER JOIN 
        company c ON (mgrc.mgr_cid = c.cid ) 
    JOIN
        handler h ON (c.handlerId = h.handlerid ) 
    WHERE
        h.handlerid = 5800657002370

INSERT INTO #parent_manager_filter 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        mc.cid,
        c.company_name as name,
        c.code as code 
    FROM
        manager_company mc 
    INNER JOIN
        company c ON (mc.mgr_cid = c.cid ) 
    JOIN
        handler h ON (h.handlerid = c.handlerid) 
    WHERE
        h.handlerid = 5800657002370 ;

WITH company AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        c.cid AS cid,
        parentManager.name AS MANAGER_NAME,
        parentManager.code AS code 
    FROM
        company c 
    LEFT JOIN
        #parent_manager parentManager ON (parentManager.cid = c.cid) 
    LEFT JOIN
        # parent_manager_filter parentManagerFilter ON (parentManagerFilter.cid = c.cid) 
    WHERE
        parentManagerFilter.name IN (:managerList)
),
total_rows AS
(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) OVER () AS TOTALCOUNT,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY company_name ASC) AS rnum,
        grid.* 
    FROM
        company grid 
)
SELECT * 
FROM total_rows rnum 
WHERE rnum >= 1 
  AND rnum <= 10 

DROP TABLE #parent_manager;
DROP TABLE #parent_manager_filter;
```

Comment: I would recommend using better measurements than "huge data" and "execution time is very large" or "lot of company" because that's so unclear nobody will know where to start. Give exact measurements, duration, table & indexing structures and query plan.

Comment: Why are you declaring `varchar(max)` whe you're data is `varchar(2000)` and I would question if you need that, also `numeric(18)` - so that's a `bigint` then? Do you *need*  that? Use *appropriate* data types - over millions of rows this will definitely help.

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question. Where is the DDL for `handler` and its index(es)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are building up temp tables then I would make sure you don't miss a clustered index, else your temp table is simply a heap. You don't have one covering the filter table.

```
INSERT INTO #parent_manager_filter ...
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cte_parent_manager_filter On #parent_manager_filter(cid);
```

Comment: Yes index has been created missed that part.

Comment: @Techie321 Did the query speed improve?

Comment: It was already there I missed to mention it over here.

Comment: Have you tried taking out the subqueries inside the selects (basically the stuffs)? Does that reduce query time?

Comment: Also, why you are at it, you might want to throw a non clustered index on #parent_manager.code and  #parent_manager_filter.code. It want hurt anything and you can compare query plans.

Comment: Is there any way that I can reduce index fetching on "( STUFF((..." because I think I am duplicating my search again and again on same table as  mentioned in INSERT INTO #parent_manager.How can I achieve desired result  with only one scan

Comment: You could try putting the STUFF statements into a third temp table with indexes on the key fields. The time to build up the temp table may be worth not having to exercise queries in the select statement the way you are doing.